# return null in ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

i have this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

function doAjax(url) {
    $("#customForm").submit(function() {
        var formdata = $("#customForm").serializeArray();
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "post",
            dataType: "json",
            data: formdata,
            success: function(data) {
                switch (data.livre) {

                case 'tituloLivre':
                    $("#msgbox2").fadeTo(200, 0.1, function() {
                        $(this).html('error').fadeTo(900, 1);
                    });
                    break;

                default:
                    $("#msgbox2").fadeTo(200, 0.1, function() {
                        $(this).html('success!').fadeTo(900, 1, function() {
                            $('#conteudo').load('test.php'); // show NULL and must be programmer
                        });
                    });
                    break;
                }
            }
        }); 
        return false;         
    }); 
}
doAjax('sent.php');
doAjax('dojo/test.php');   
});
</script>
```

test.php

```
<?php
include ('includesMy.php');
$form = $_POST['item'];
$oferta = $form['oferta'];

var_dump($oferta);

?>
```

what is sent:

```
item[oferta] programmer
```

**The question is: why i get null value instead of programmer word ?**

POST test.php - returns programmer, but GET test.php returns null. Basically the load (test.php) is retrieved without ajax influence.

Comment: test.php return null value and must be programmer

Comment: What's going on here? Where's this `url` parameter comping from? The `$(document).ready` callback doesn't take any parameters. Where's the `doAjax` function being called? What is your question? At its current state this one is likely to get closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server response should be valid [JSON](http://json.org/). Use the [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) PHP function at the server's side to return a valid JSON string.

Comment: That's half of the answer. The client side shown in the question seems pretty broken as well.

Comment: is not the problem, var_dump should show programmer word in firebug. Only show null.